# HTML Validators not working when using KendoUI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, validation, kendo-ui

I'm using kendo ui on MVC. 
I have validators like `[Required] , [Range]` etc on my variables. 
But when using Kendo controls on the html page these validations are not working and the page is posted. 
What I'm i doing wrong here?
Isnt it supposed to convert default html validators to Kendo automatically?

I think the problem is with this scrpit:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

If its deleted no client side validation occurs. If its inserted Kendo controls doesn't function.

**EDIT :**

I found the following thread in the KendoUI Forum => [Using Kendo Validator with MVC Model Properties](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-framework/validation/using-kendo-validator-with-mvc-model-properties.aspx)

None of the solutions provided a solutions to my problem. Hope someone on SO could help me.

Comment: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/validator/index.html

Comment: The link in no way provide an answer to my question